# Existence of a kernel in induced subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

Theorem (The Dinitz Problem - **M. Aigner, Günter M. Ziegler: *Proofs from THE BOOK* (4th edition)**):

> Consider $n^2$ cells arranged in an $(n × n)$-square, and let $(i, j)$
>   de- note the cell in row $i$ and column $j$. Suppose that for every
>   cell $(i, j)$ we are given a set $C(i, j)$ of $n$ colors. Is it then
>   always possible to color the whole array by picking for each cell $(i,
>  j)$ a color from its set $C(i, j)$ such that the colors in each row
>   and each column are distinct?

I'd like to ask if someone can explain me the following statement. How that condition ensures us that there is a kernel for all induced subgraphs?

> We have to find an orientation of the graph $S_n$ with outdegrees
>   $d^+(v) \le n-1$ for all $v$ which ensures the existence of a kernel
>   for all induced subgraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misread the sentence.  It says:

> We have to find an orientation of the graph $S_n$ with outdegrees $d^+(v) \leq n−1$ for all $v$ **and** which ensures the existence of a kernel for all induced subgraphs.

I.e., the goal is to find the orientation for the [rook's graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook%27s_graph) $S_n$ which satisfies the conditions of Lemma 1.

Comment: Thanks, that wiki page is also nice!